# Getting empty error box after clicking ok button on my screen.

Tags: ewam

Code is written such that clicking Ok button accepts current object. Getting empty error box with no message while running on the application. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have overriden the IsValid method but not given any code inside the method. So it returns False by default and shows empty message

Comment: Yes. I now removed the IsValid method from my code which was never used and not needed. Thanks